# Can't Get JavaScript Forms To Access Value and Send Alert

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was messing around with forms, and I was working with a JSfiddle, and I couldn't get the page to return an alert.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="first"></input>
<input type="text" id="last"></input>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="construct()"></input>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function construct() {
var firstName = document.getElementById("first").value;
var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value;
alert("Welcome to the party " + firstName + " " + lastName + "!");
}
```

And I can't tell why it is not returning a value. Any help is appreciated!
Oh and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nickpalmer789/4DJ4e/1/
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the fiddle is set up to run onload so the function is not available in global scope. Either change it to run in the head or on the body

[image]

or attach the event handler in a non obtrusive way.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = construct;
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do this, so that I can make it in a regular javascript file?

Comment: Explain how to go into the drop down and select the other option as shown in the image above?

Comment: Sorry, I meant what do the different options mean?

Comment: Read the docs: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `onload` (top left) to `no wrap - in <head>`. You're interfering with scope, so `construct()` isn't declared in the global scope (which the `onclick` attribute is looking for).

Otherwise, declare it as `window.construct = function(){ ... }`

As an aside, you should really be keeping markup and javascript separated. that is to say don't use the `on*` attributes of elements, and instead bind to them within javascript. Something like:

```
<!-- give n ID to the button -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn" />

<script>
  // grab the button (using the ID)
  var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
  // attach en event handler for click
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // construct() code goes here
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the difference between all of the different options on that menu are used for?

Comment: @NickP: [`onLoad`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload), [`onDomReady`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded), `no wrap - in <head>` just places it directly in the `<head>` of the document, and `no wrap - in <body>` places in within the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`construct` is defined inside another function, so it isn't a global and isn't accessible to intrinsic event attributes.

Don't use intrinsic event attributes, bind your event handlers with JS.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', construct);
```

Such: http://jsfiddle.net/4DJ4e/3/